# Ruby function definition

Tags: ruby, function

How do I define a function in Ruby so that such call `f[true,1,2,3]` could be made?
I tried something like this 
`def f(arr)
...
end`
But it requires `f([true,1,2,3])`.
I'm total newb in Ruby, just need it to complete certain task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
class MyClass
    def [](a,b,c,d)
        print "#{a} #{b} #{c} #{d}"
    end
end

f = MyClass.new

f[true,1,2,3]   # => true 1 2 3
```